After adjust the height of q-input, floating lable tip was broken
I read this tutorial to make my q-input looks bigger than default, here is my code and codepen:
vue
<q-input
  ref="emailInputBox"
  outlined
  v-model="email"
  label="Email"
  type="email"
  class="input-box"
  @input="validateEmail"
>
  <template v-slot:label>
    <div>Email</div>
  </template>
</q-input>

css
:deep(.input-box .q-field__control),
:deep(.input-box .q-field__marginal) {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

Unfortunately, after resize the height of input box, the position of the label is broken:
the input box image
As above image shown, the label is no longer in the center of input box, so how to style it and I don't want to broke its
floating animation.
let label correctly center and animation.

Its because top: 18px; is set on the label, so you also need to update that styling as per your need, like in current case it can be top: 30px;

@YashMaheshwari yeah, very thanks for your replay! top:30px will add more space to it, but the animation or transition is still broken, if you want correct floating animation, it is not enough to complete this work.

you can adjust that using transform translate


.input-box .q-field__control,
.input-box .q-field__marginal {
  height: 75px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.input-box .q-field__label {
  font-size: 20px;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-out;
}

.input-box.q-field--float .q-field__label {
  transform: translateY(-50%) scale(0.55);
}



Adjust the font size and translateY as needed.

Totally works fine! This solve my problem, I noticed that change the height of q-input box is very diffcult to done caused by its complex in the black box, and there is not have some offical way or api to do. Thanks for your reply.
